# (How-to) JavaScript - Test for Unsigned Integer (UINT) using Regular Expressions (RegExp)

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem**: How to test/check if a value is an Unsigned Integer (*UINT*) in ***JavaScript***.

**Alternative Answers**:
Thanks goes to the following for improving this answer!

@**jbabey**:`if Number(val) > 0`

@**SLaks**:`if (/^\d+$/.test(someString))`

---

**About**: This shows how to test/check if a value is an Unsigned Integer (*UINT*) in ***JavaScript***.

---

**Usage**: `JS: isUINT( value );`

---

**Returns**: `True` *OR* `False`

---

**Expanded Version**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isUINT(v)
    {
        var r = RegExp(/(^[^\-]{0,1})?(^[\d]*)$/);
        return r.test(v) && v.length > 0;
    }
</script>
```

---

**Minified Version**:

```
function isUINT(v){var r=RegExp(/(^[^\-]{0,1})?(^[\d]*)$/);return r.test(v)&&v.length>0}
```

---

*Comments / Alternatives are Welcomed!*

Comment: I don't think this question makes sense. There's no such thing as an "unsigned" type in JavaScript, so *no* value will *ever* be an "unsigned integer".  If you just mean "non-negative integer", then there are better ways to do it than a regular expression.

Comment: @Pointy: Correct. There is no such thing as an 'Unsigned' type in JavaScript. I wanted to make one.

Answer (score 10):

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(someString))
```

​

Comment: Thank you for this insightful post! It is simple and to the point.
I did a bit more research on RegExp for JS and found it not as native to the language, yet rather it is an extra layer.

Comment: @TrentonBost: Wrong.  The Javascript language supports regex literals, and the Javascript spec mandates the `RegExp` class.  However, regexes are not primitives.

Comment: Exactly, the <code>RegExp</code> class is an extra layer of processing. It isn't as native than how I have used it in Python or Perl, hence my comment 'isn't as native'. It is costly in JS.

Comment: @TrentonBost: That isn't really true.  The `RegExp` class is implemented by the host.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but now you can use

```js
const isUINT = (val) => Number.isInteger(val) && val >= 0

console.log('"a":', isUINT('a'))
console.log('"1":', isUINT('1'))
console.log('null:', isUINT(null))
console.log('-1:', isUINT(-1))
console.log('0:', isUINT(0))
console.log('1:', isUINT(1))
console.log('1.25:', isUINT(1.25))
console.log('0.25:', isUINT(0.25))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Alternative Answers**:
Thanks goes to the following for improving this answer!

@**jbabey**:`if Number(val) > 0`

@**SLaks**:`if (/^\d+$/.test(someString))`

---

**About**: This shows how to test/check if a value is an Unsigned Integer (*UINT*) in ***JavaScript***.

---

**Usage**: `JS: isUINT( value );`

---

**Returns**: `True` *OR* `False`

---

**Expanded Version**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isUINT(v)
    {
        var r = RegExp(/(^[^\-]{0,1})?(^[\d]*)$/);
        return r.test(v) && v.length > 0;
    }
</script>
```

---

**Minified Version**:

```
function isUINT(v){var r=RegExp(/(^[^\-]{0,1})?(^[\d]*)$/);return r.test(v)&&v.length>0}
```

---

*Comments / Alternatives are Welcomed!*

Comment: Your regex is needlessly complex.

Comment: I don't think this even works.  There's also no reason to invoke the RegExp constructor when you build the regular expression with native syntax.

Comment: @Pointy: It does work, because the second `^` makes the first group not match anything.

Comment: Ah OK, I missed that.  Well I still think the whole premise is flawed;' a regex, after all, operates on *strings*, and by some interpretation of the OP strings aren't unsigned integers at all :-)

Comment: @Pointy: The goal isn't to return a string, integer, number, etc.. The goal is to determine if the argument passed (whatever it may be - string, number, array, etc...) is an UINT.
It simply returns TRUE or FALSE as outlined above.

Once again, alternatives are welcomed!

Comment: Super bad regexp, "x{0,1}" is same as "x?"